# Why can't I access LAN servers in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, lan, gaming, minecraft

I upgraded my laptop to Windows 10, and now I can't see LAN servers (Minecraft, COD, etc).

If I start a LAN server from my desktop I am not able to connect to this server from my laptop. (I tried direct connect too). The Minecraft tells me:

> *Failed to login: Invalid session*

My laptop and desktop are on the same network. Before the upgrade it worked perfectly, but now I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Are both gateways and subnets the same?

Comment: Where can I see this?

Comment: Can you open the command prompt? I know in windows 7, you can press windows key + r, type cmd into the run dialog and click ok.  Once in command prompt type ipconfig

Comment: This is the two ipconfig command:    http://kepfeltoltes.hu/150912/kpe11111_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg
Soo the gateway and subnet are the same and still not works. When I hade WIN7 on my laptop it worked good, but after update it is not OK.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is an old question it remains unanswered and as i encountered the same problem, which took me some while to figure out, i'm sharing my solution here.

If whitelisting your application/ports in the firewall **does not work**, this might:

If you have several network interfaces, disable all interfaces you do not use/need for accessing the server in question. You can do this as follows:

1. Open the Control Panel
2. Open Network and Sharing Center
3. Click on "Change Adapter Settings"
4. For all adapters you **don't need**: right click -> deactivate

Answer (score 0):

There's a few possibility.

1. Your computer has not been appointed a IPv4 IP (Mostly not, but possible if you're using a router)
2. If you're trying to connect to a lan server host by computer A using computer B, check whether computer A and computer B are on the same network or not.
3. If you're trying to connect to a lan server host by computer A using computer B via tools such as hamachi, check whether computer B has connected to a same network of computer A. (You should know what I mean if you're using them, and if you don't, you can ignore this)
4. You haven't connected into the internet (But seems that you can get into this website, isn't it?)
5. Your firewall is on and has blocked your connection between your game and the lan server. If this is the case, add the server port to the whitelist ON THE SERVER SIDE.

If these couldn't help you, give me a downvote and go check out other players' solutions.

Edit: one more, if the server host is using router, make sure the router is port forwarding the right port, and make sure that you use the Service Port to connect to the server instead of the Internal Port.

Comment: Yesterday I turned off the firewall, and it worked good. I added the all local port to the whitelist, and it worked well. Today i tried to play lan, but i can't because the problem is the same. I turned off the firewall again but it did not help, I can  not see the lan server from my laptop.

Comment: Check whether your ip is changed or not, or see whether your router was reset or not.

Comment: My ip is always changing (dynamic ip), and the router was reset two days ago.